# Selecting multiple check boxes in a group using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have to select many checkboxes in a group there are 10 checkboxes with value attribute set from 0 to 9 now if i have to provide a list like  ["1","3","8"] by user and i have to select checkbox with value 1 ,3 and 8.How to accomplsh?? please reply !!

Comment: You want to find which checkboxes were checked by the user, or you have to check specific checkboxes according to an array you receive from somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = ['1','3','8'];
/* find all the checkbox input elements.
   set the 'checked' property */
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(){
    // return  true if the value is in the array, false if not
    return $.inArray(this.value, arr) > -1;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zdSX5/1/).

Or, using `filter()`:

```
var arr = ['1','3','8'];

$('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, arr) > -1;
}).prop('checked',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zdSX5/2/).

It might be worth, however, first unchecking any already-checked checkboxes before you set the property:

```
var arr = ['1','3','8'];

$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false).filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, arr) > -1;
}).prop('checked',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zdSX5/4/).

Finally, because the `value` of an `input` is always a string, whereas numbers in JavaScript don't have to be quoted, to allow for unquoted numbers in the array (to guard against forgetfulness, if nothing else):

```
var arr = ['1',3,'8'];

$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false).filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.value, arr.toString()) > -1;
}).prop('checked',true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zdSX5/6/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`jQuery.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

Answer (score 1):

By example, for the value 8 :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="myGroup[]" value="7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="myGroup[]" value="8" />

<script>
  $(".chk[value='8']").prop("checked", true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it - give your checkboxes a common class, i.e. "myCheckbox".

Use jQuery to iterate through all the checkboxes with the class "myCheckbox", and compare their value with the list provided by the user. If there's a match, select the checkbox.

Pseudo jQuery code:

```
$('.myCheckbox').each(function() {
  // you would search the array here
  if ($(this).value == "1") {
    $(this).check();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
var arr =  ["1","3","8"];
$(':checkbox').each(function(){
  if($.inArray(this.value,arr) > -1){
   $(this).prop('checked',true);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your issue:

```
var setArr = ["1","3","8"];

$('.checkbox').each(function(i, j){
if(jQuery.inArray($(j).val(), setArr)!= -1){

$(j).attr('checked', 'checked');
}

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3afrA/)